# How to convert a .mb file from Maya

Tags: maya

About 10 years ago I worked with 3D animations in Maya™ 4.0.2. I still have one of the animations as a .mb file. I would like to play it now, years later, but I don't have access to Maya anymore.

How can I open this file and convert it to something generic format like .mov or .mp4?

I googled it, of course, but I didn't find any solutions.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not involve programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to any computer, you could install a 30 day demo version of Maya and try to read it. Otherwise you will have to ask someone owning Maya to convert it for you.